# Confirming delivery of reading of messages (chat)?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way confirm the delivery and reading of messages sent to a client?

I would like to do something similar to WhatsApp where it provides two types of confirmation, the first is a delivery and the second is a reading confirmation.

Is there a way around this or something that is supported?

Comment: Yes you can. On the client, write something that detects if the message appeared and if it was likely that the user had it visible to them. Can't know for sure they actually see or read it though.

Comment: The simple way to do this is to send specific events for delivery, and display of message back to the server.  Very simple, and what socket.io was built to do.